# How to debug C++ memory errors?

Tags: c++

Does valgrind work with STL allocator? I am using STL vector with plain C library in the follwing fashion:

```
double some_C_functions(int, double*);

std::vector<double> v;
.....
double result = some_C_functions(v.size(), &v[0]);
```

What if the C functions tries to overshoot the pointer? Can valgrind detect the error?

Comment: Please tell us what `some_C_functions1 does

Comment: Read or writing on the overshoot though.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind should still be able to detect that since it's hooking into the memory management which still goes to the same heap for C or C++. Obviously it's hard(er) to detect errant reads though.